# Why CAST from Date time to varchar works in one Environment but not the other?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

For this questions, we have two environments, Dev and Prod with both running sql2014 with dev being a developers version and prod an enterprise version.  Dev is running the below version(s)

[image]

Prod is running the below version(s)

[image]

Both are using the same data set (static data set from prod. DB was restored from Prod to Dev today), but when casting from Date/time to Varchar in Dev, its throws a conversation error, but in our Prod environment, it works just fine.

Could the difference in version we see here be the reason it doesnt work in our lower environment.

Here is the Dev Exact version #: SELECT @@Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194714) - 12.0.5203.0 (X64) 
Sep 23 2016 18:13:56 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Prod Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Here is my SQL, its apart of a CTE Update statement if wondering what the hell im doing:

```
 SELECT W.[order number], W.[BO NUMBER]
,CAST(MAX(cast(CT.[trans-date] as varchar) + ' ' + CT.[CHAR-OLD]) as date) AS 'TDate'
,SUBSTRING(cast(CAST(MAX(cast(CT.[trans-date] as varchar) + ' ' + CT.[CHAR-OLD]) as time(0))as varchar),1,5) as 'TTime'

FROM [dbo].[PURCHASE_TO_PORCH_WORK] W

            inner join dbo.[change_tracking] ct
            on W.[ORDER NUMBER]= ct.[document-num]
            and ct.[bo-number] = W.[BO NUMBER]

WHERE ct.[change-id] = 'WTRCV'
and W.[ACTION CODE] = 'SI'
group by [ORDER NUMBER], [BO NUMBER]
```

Date Types (Both Env):

[trans-date] = (date, null)

[char-old] = (varchar(16), null)

Comment: Most likely different execution plans as `CT.[CHAR-OLD]) as date)` isn't safe. Can't say if the different plans are due to the  different patch levels.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM dbo.change_tracking WHERE CHAR_OLD IS NOT NULL AND (TRY_CAST('abc' as date) IS NULL OR TRY_CAST('abc' as time(0)) IS NULL);`.

Comment: also suggest using TRY_CAST, but think you really need TRY_CONVERT **with style number** too often see folks relying on default style such as mm/dd/yyyy. btw: would really need to see data to know what style number is required

Comment: Are the collations the same?

Comment: @Sparky we are looking into that now the current suggestions all resulted in the same error.  We are thinking its collations at this point but looking to see if patches on the server were also installed upgrading a version some where.

Comment: Issue was actually DB compatibility level. Supposed to be set to 2008 (100) but was 2014 (120).  i also go it working in 2014 (120) compatibility by not casting CT.[trans-date] as varchar.  Even though that answer wasnt provided, the suggestion helped me trouble shoot so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was actually DB compatibility level. Supposed to be set to 2008 (100) but was 2014 (120). i also go it working in 2014 (120) compatibility by not casting CT.[trans-date] as varchar. Even though that answer wasnt provided, the suggestion helped me trouble shoot so much appreciated!